# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Invalid page index range : 0 - -1 of 0

Tags: java, jasper-reports

When I try printing the Jasper report it gets me the message:  "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Invalid page index range : 0 - -1 of 0".

Code:

```
    try {
        JasperPrint impressao = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("example.jasper"), parametros);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(impressao);

        JasperPrintManager.printReport(impressao, true);  
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="base-estadual" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9cbb7afc-abb5-4207-a29b-a0c7adde7df6">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="250"/>
<import value="com.myproject.ed.*"/>
<parameter name="PATH_IMAGENS" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="63">
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="515" y="16" width="40" height="20" uuid="3892152b-6880-41da-bbc7-7bf79588061d"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]>/textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
```

Could someone help me to figure out why is it happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JasperFillManager likes to get a data source, even when you don't really have any. You could try adding an empty data source as a third parameter to JasperFillManager.fillReport:

```
JasperPrint impressao = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("example.jasper"), parametros, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the parameters which you are passing to the `JasperFillManager.fillReport()` is not null or empty. If it is empty or null then you will receive this same error.

```
 JasperPrint impressao = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("example.jasper"), parametros);
```